# Getting number of votes that have been cast for a model in Active Record Reputation System

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am using the Active Record Reputation System with Rails 3.1.0.  I have a model that users can vote up or vote down.  How do I determine how many times a particular model instance has been voted on?  I would like to be able to say "x of y users up-voted this item."  How do I get y?

Comment: Can you give more information, how are the votes stored, how are the votes generated?

Comment: Tried to make my question clearer. I think I found the answer though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I have a model that has reputation and I have an instance of the model, model_instance, then it looks like I can get the total number of votes with:

```
model_instance.evaluations.count
```